# CSRF token mismatch on hosting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, csrf-token

I have laravel project on an hosting domain. Now I need to upload the same project on another domain. After uploading it I am getting csrf mismatch errors. while it was working fine on the previous domain. the errors are shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtrCy.png)

I am using csrf directive in my blade templates and also in my scripts files.

```
@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post('{{ route('home.section.featured') }}', {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function(data){
            $('#section_featured').html(data);
            slickInit();
        });

        $.post('{{ route('home.section.best_selling') }}', {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function(data){
            $('#section_best_selling').html(data);
            slickInit();
        });

        $.post('{{ route('home.section.home_categories') }}', {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function(data){
            $('#section_home_categories').html(data);
            slickInit();
        });

        $.post('{{ route('home.section.best_sellers') }}', {_token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'}, function(data){
            $('#section_best_sellers').html(data);
            slickInit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

@endsection

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: tried it, still not working

Comment: If you can, do not add the image as a link. Someday the link will stop working and your question, however best it may be, will become useless. Add graphics as image or code as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue.
In index.php file in public folder call function ob_start().

This function will take the contents of the output buffer and returns a string that is to be sent to the browser for rendering and removes the spaces or line breaks you put before starting php.